# Can't get CommandTarget in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Say, I have the following XAML:

```xml
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="WPFApp.Root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:r="urn:fluent-ribbon"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="FL Query" Height="450" Width="800">

  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" Executed="OnCopy"/>
  </Window.CommandBindings>
  
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <r:Ribbon Grid.Row="0">

      <r:RibbonTabItem Header="Home">
        <r:RibbonGroupBox Header="ID">
          <r:TextBox x:Name="txtID" Header="ID:" Width="100"/>
          <r:Button Size="Large"
                    LargeIcon="pack://application:,,,/WPFApp;component/img/Run.png" 
                    Click="OnAction">
                    Content="Run"/>
        </r:RibbonGroupBox>
      </r:RibbonTabItem>

    </r:Ribbon>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <Label x:Name="lbl">
        <Label.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
                      CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=lbl}"/>
          </ContextMenu>
        </Label.ContextMenu>
      </Label>
    </Grid>

  </Grid>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

Upon pressing `Run` button I retrieve ID number from database and put it to label. Then I'm trying to copy label's text (i.e. this ID) with label's context menu by using `CommandTarget`. However, `e.Source` holds reference to previously pressed `Run` button:

```cs
private void OnCopy(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // sender = WPFApp.Root
  // e.Source = Fluent.Ribbon
  // e.OriginalSource = class "Fluent.Button": Header = "Run", Size = Large, IsSimplified = false
    
  // label is NULL here
  var label = e.Source as Label;
  Clipboard.SetText(label.Content.ToString());
}
```

Why `CommandTarget` doesn't work? Why do I get `Button` (Run) instead of a label?

Comment: Because the Button is what triggered the event.  So `e.Source` is the Button, not the Label.

Comment: @RobertHarvey H-m-m... Doesn't menu item trigger the action?

Comment: It should, if you wrote the code correctly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have made test when I added brand new button next to `Run` button (say, "ExportData"). And made following actions: Press "Run" -> Press "Export Data" -> Copy in Label's menu, and voíla - the source is "Export Data"!

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: @JohnyL: If you want the `Content` of the `Label`, why don't you just handle the `Click` event of the `MenuItem`? The command target is the object that the copy command is being executed on, i.e. the object from which you copy.

Comment: @mm8 I know that I can do it, but I wonder why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextMenu` is a popup window, that means that it has different name scope then its owner. So `ElementName` will not work in this situation. The right way is use `ContextMune.PlacementTarget` to reference to the owner.

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
          CommandTarget="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```

And about you getting `Button` instead of `Label`, I just can't reproduce that. Normally, if a `MenuItem` can't solve its `CommandTarget`, it should be disabled automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!!  Now it works as intended! You have earned +150!!! 